# Rspec expanding upon basic user tests with user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to build upon some existing tests but i am unsure how to approach the syntax i need. My user has diagnostic info which is much like a posts concept. I am trying to write a test for the model which checks that if a user exists with an id then it will be assigned and therefore it will be a valid user. I understand that to check if a user is valid i would need to do something similar to the following:

```
 user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
 expect(user).to be_valid
```

My confusion is how do i build upon this and check that a user exists that exists with an id will be assigned diagnostic info.

DiagnosticInfo Model:

```
class DiagnosticInfo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  default_scope where(completed_at: nil)

  belongs_to :user 
  field :data, type: Hash
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :notes, type: String
  field :completed_at, type: DateTime

  validates :data, presence: true

  before_create :assign_user

  index created_at: 1

  def complete
    touch :completed_at
  end

  private 

  def assign_user
    if user_id
      user = User.where(auth_system_user_id: self.user_id).first
      self.user = user 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you asking how to make sure that you cannot create diagnosticinfo without a userID? and how to test it? Normally in FactoryGirl you would make your `DiagnosticInfoFactory` to build the User for you when you create the model (If  you needed a specific user, you can pass one in, or use traits, etc..).  If you wanted to test that Validations on DiagnosticInfo don't allow you to create an instance w/o a userid, you can pass in nil.  but still a bit lost about what you are asking .

Comment: I just want to know how to test that a user with diagnostic info attached in valid but i am unsure as to how to add this to the existing syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this would be to ensure that the validations in your `User` model ensure that there is a corresponding `DiagnosticInfo`.

Then in your test, create a `User` using a factory. Ensure it is not valid unless a corresponding `DiagnosticInfo` record is created.

```
u = create(:user)
expect(u).not_to be_valid
# Some code that creates a diagnostic info
expect(u).to be_valid
```

Comment: Thanks this is a wonderful help. Would you be able just to explain how this works with regards to testing a user id?

Comment: What do you mean by 'testing a user id'?

Comment: Just that in order for a user to have diagnostic info then they should have a user id. If they don't have a user id then there is no user with Diagnostic Info. Having said this is feel now this is probably the same as checking a user exists but because it is not in my user model i think i might be getting wires crossed.